# Building PHP from source for use in Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm having trouble when installing an older version of PHP (5.1) on a Ubuntu machine. I've tried to downgrade it without success using apt-get, so I tried to install from source. After the installation, typing php -v in the terminal results in the correct version (i.e. 5.1), but the version that apache uses keep the same (the older one: 5.4) if I view it through

How do I add the installation I just did to apache in place of the older one? I need to remove the older version and make apache recognize the version I just installed.

Comment: You need to adjust your `httpd.conf` to point to the PHP module for your custom installation. Look for the `LoadModule` line for php and point it to the `.so` for your custom install.

Comment: @prodigitalson How do I find the path for the new version installed from source?

Comment: Well start looking in whatever prefix you used... I'm also not 100% but it may not build the apache module by default you may need to do that as an extra step or if easier compile again with some particular flags to `configure`.